# Removing back slashed from binary data stored in database

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I am working on an legacy application in which images where saved in DB as string and rendered to client as headers where ever required.
Recently some one added a callback function on save method of cakePHP Model, which is adding backslashes to binary data of image.

Now, this is causing problem when rendering the image, could not find out how to remove those backslashes.

I have tried

```
quoted_printable_decode()
```

and `removeslashes()`

kindly suggest appropriate solution for this.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have access to the backslash-adding code? I would work from there to understand the exact way the backslashes are added and call, if possible, the reverse function when they are served. Or even better, have the backslash-adding code removed.

Comment: What does quoted printable encodign have to do with the question? What happened when you tried `removeslashes()`? Why not just stop adding slashes?